# How to get packets queued by the kernel packet filter?

Tags: debian, networking, raspbian, proxy, qos

I made simple HTTP proxy which accepts connections from clients on a fixed port; the proxy forks for every incoming connection, and the forked process deals with the flow of packets to the Internet and from the Internet; a simple QOS is implemented, packets are stored in three different queues according to their level of priority (minimum, medium, maximum) and then sent in order of priority.

So far so good, but my proxy is not exactly where it is supposed to be: the proxy is on my laptop, and the clients supposed to connect to the proxy is only my laptop: so the proxy is working, but this is not a real case (I don't want a proxy on a local machine, I want it "outside" of it).

Now that the testing phase is over, I want to migrate my proxy on an external entity, where (I guess) it's supposed to be: for example, my Raspberry Pi 2 **but** before telling me to migrate this question, please hear about my problem. I read the questions in Raspberry Stack Exchange and they are all about sensors, how to connect the Pi to a monitor or issues about Bluetooth.

My issue is about libraries in the underlying OS, Raspbian, a Debian derived OS optimized, so I thought this Stack Exchange would be the appropriate place.

I tried a first approach with `libnetfilter_queue` (always with proxy on my laptop) and with the `iptables` flag, `NFQUEUE`, I had my queue(s) of packets (to copy in a queue of mine, `DROP` them and send them again when the time has come with a raw socket): but my RPi may be multi-interface (it may have up to four Wi-Fi dongles inserted, since it is an Access Point, plus the Ethernet cable with which it is connected to my modem), and my supervisor said `libnetfilter_queue` is not suited for my purpose, since it cannot deal with more than one interface, and it has diffucult on choosing what interface to use to send packets.

In summary: I have a proxy on my laptop, I'd like to migrate it in my RPi (so, in addition to be an Access Point, it should also offer QOS) but I don't know how to redirect the packets from one `wlan0` interface (or all four of them) to my proxy, designed to listen on a port passed to the `main` program.

`libnetfilter_queue` is (apparently) not an option, so what library/API may I use?

This is part of my thesis, so I prefer to use libraries and/or APIs to integrate with my code, not to use already existing programs.

Thanks for your help.